# How to optimize streaming aggregation with socket data source?

Tags: scala, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql, spark-structured-streaming

I use Spark 2.4.0 with Scala 2.11 on 4 CPU cores and 8 threads.

I wrote the following application:

```
package demos.spark

object WordCounter {

  def main(args: Array[String]): Unit = {
    import org.apache.spark.sql.SparkSession
    val spark = SparkSession
      .builder
      .master("local[4]")
      .getOrCreate
    import spark.implicits._
    spark
      .readStream
      .format("socket")
      .option("host", "localhost")
      .option("port", 9999)
      .load
      .as[String]
      .flatMap(_.split("\\W+"))
      .groupBy("value")
      .count
      .writeStream
      .outputMode("complete")
      .format("console")
      .start
      .awaitTermination
  }
}
```

The processing time for the application with `local[1]` takes ~60 seconds. For `local[8]` it drops to ~15 seconds and that is the minimal value I have ever got.

I always send one or two sentences via socket as an input.

Is it an expected behaviour? How to optimize the application to have a 1-second processing time?

EDIT:
After long hours spent on this problem, finally I've got a solution. The problem was in too many partisions (few hundreds) that were default used by Spark. After adding spark.sql.shuffle.partitions option set to 8 (number of cores on my machine), the duration of data processing have been declined to 300-400 ms

```
val spark = SparkSession
  .builder
  .master("local[*]")
  .config("spark.sql.shuffle.partitions", 8)
  .getOrCreate
```

I don't know yet, if this number should be constant or not, what if Spark application will be running on infrastructure that could be changing (Spark, Kubernetes, AWS, autoscaling)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> 4 CPU cores and 8 threads.

Use `local[*]` and Spark will use as many processing threads as there are cores, i.e. 4. If these 8 threads are virtual cores, Spark will see 8 "CPU cores" so 8 is the maximum number of threads for processing.

And that's exactly what your tests have proved, i.e.

> For `local[8]` it drops to ~15 seconds and that is the minimal value I have ever got.
>
> Is it an expected behaviour?

Yes and it's hardly possible to beat the time unless you change the processing logic, i.e. the structured query itself. That's where I usually say to think about the algorithm (that may possibly be different per the data to process). You're constraint by the number of CPU cores available.

> How to optimize the application to have a 1-second processing time?

Change your structured query ("the algorithm") or the way it works under the covers.

The following operations are the processing logic:

```
.flatMap(_.split("\\W+"))
.groupBy("value")
.count
```

`flatMap` is cheap and can get as fast as there are CPU cores. You can't do much about it.

You also use a streaming aggregation `groupBy` followed by `count` that changes the number of tasks required for execution (in your case it'd be from 8 to the default number of shuffle partitions, i.e. 200).

You can count the number of CPU ticks required to run 200 tasks on 8 cores and you will need that much time to compute the result.

> The problem was in too many partisions (few hundreds) that were default used by Spark. After adding spark.sql.shuffle.partitions option set to 8 (number of cores on my machine), the duration of data processing have been declined to 300-400 ms

Sure that has helped in this particular case and that's OK if that's the only hardware you may ever have. You're done.

What about other environments where the number of cores could go much higher?

> if this number should be constant or not, what if Spark application will be running on infrastructure that could be changing (Spark, Kubernetes, AWS, autoscaling)?

That's the hardest question to answer. Welcome to the very dynamic / highly-configurable world of Apache Spark. There are so many factors to influence the final result that often what you have is what you should end up with or you start tweaking the [many configuration options](http://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/configuration.html) and you will have to spend hours or weeks figuring out what the best configuration should be. Think of the different data that your streaming query will process (data shape, volume and velocity). It adds up to confusion.

Wearing consulting hat, at some point you will have to decide whether the application performance is good enough or you are going to spend weeks hoping that you can do better than what you've already achieved (and someone has to pay for it).

> if this number should be constant or not

It should if you know all the data you will ever process so you can make such a hard assumption.

It should not in general and that's why Spark gives you [Adaptive Query Execution](https://jaceklaskowski.gitbooks.io/mastering-spark-sql/spark-sql-adaptive-query-execution.html) ([video](https://databricks.com/session/an-adaptive-execution-engine-for-apache-spark-sql)).